# Is there any User Interface offered to view the AWS Textract OCR output side-by-side the source document?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ocr, amazon-textract

The AWS textract outputs a JSON result after passing it a document. I'm interested in using this output to somehow view a side-by-side of the source document(say pdf) and the output in some way. 
Is this supported by any tool right now?

For example, how exactly are api developer customers using the output in a UI type of way in order to see how the results compare to the source? Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Here is perhaps an example, but not for AWS output schema

https://github.com/kba/hocrjs

Answer (score 3):

The Textract console has a demo where you can view the detected data against the input PDF or image file: https://console.aws.amazon.com/textract/home?#/demo

The demo has the following limits:

> - It must be smaller than 5 MB, and have fewer than 10 pages.
> - The limits for uploading a document in the console are different than the API.

Screenshot:

[image: Textract console demo]

Comment: Can you specifically point out where exactly this is? I dont see anything on that page that states I can view the detected data against the input PDF. Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: I'd love to see an example of this. Would you be kind enough to take a screenshot of a sample of what that looks like?

Comment: Updated the link to point to the demo directly and added a screenshot.

Comment: Awesome. It would be nice though if there was a tool like this that could be used by people other than engineer types. It looks like its just available within console? Is there a version that is decoupled from Console? Many people who could use this tool wont be able to access AWS console within enterprises.

Comment: I am not aware of any other such tool which provides this interface as seen on the Textract console. You would have to use the Textract API operations to build your own version as per your requirements.